# Convert String into byte in VB

Tags: vb.net, string, type-conversion, byte

```
dim str as string
str = "111111111"

Mask1.Text = (CByte((m1)))
```

I need this code to turn this str value into "255". The decimal value from a string, anyone know how to do this? i keep getting an error with my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Convert.ToByte`:

```
Dim value As Byte = Convert.ToByte(str, 2)
```

`2` sets the base which will be used to parse your input to *binary*.

But, your input is too large for `Byte`. I think you meant to convert `"11111111"` (8x1), not `"111111111"` (9x1);